# replace current url without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, url, vaadin

I want to take the current URL from browser and replace the last number param by other number, my example URL:

```
app#!folder/1/document?p=1
```

the param to replace - ?p=1 into ?p=3

the param number is generated dynamically so I have to take the param from URL

I want to execute this JavaScript as String,
thanks a lot for any help

Comment: What do you mean with 'execute this JS as String"? As you tagged it with vaadin isn't it's Navigator that you use for navigation? In this case shouldn't your link look like app#!folder/1/document/1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reslove the problem(VAADIN FRAMEWROK) without using javascript

```
String url = Page.getCurrent().getUriFragment().toString();
url = url.replaceAll("\\?p=([0-9])?", "?p=1");
Page.getCurrent().setUriFragment(url, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, just use [String#replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Freplace) like so

```
url = url.replace("?p=1", "?p=3");
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to make this by JavaScript, the number is dynamically generated so I have to take the actual parameter and replace him

Comment: Yes. Convert it like '?p='+i, assuming you have it in "i"

Comment: So, how to execute this by javaScript

Answer (score 0):

Note that a modification to the current URL will reload the page unless it happens in the hash part (after the `#` character), which is obviously what you're trying to do.

The current URL can be modified in javascript via the `location.href` variable:

```
location.href = location.href.replace("p=1", "p=3");
```